# SQL) I'm trying to compare successive rows in SQL query using "date" as a key. Lead() method gives me syntax error

Tags: sql, stock, weekend

My Database include every weekdays for each stocks [daily_price]:

| Stock | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2018-06-01 | 100$ |
| Apple | 2018-06-02 | 130$ |
| Apple | 2018-06-03 | 143$ |
| Apple | 2018-06-04 | 286$ |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Google | 2021-03-13 | 3000$ |
| Google | 2021-03-14 | 3900$ |
| Google | 2021-03-15 | 7800$ |
| Google | 2021-03-16 | 3900$ |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to make a query that looks like this:

(trying to see movements of the next 3 days of stocks that has gone up more than 30% on D+1)

| Stock | From | To | D+1 % | D+2 % | D+3 % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2018-06-02 | 2018-06-04 | +30% | +10% | +100% |
| Apple | 2021-03-14 | 2021-03-16 | +30% | +100% | -50% |

My query [tried to used lead()] is as follows:

```
WITH comparing_price AS (
    SELECT
        CODE, DATE, OPEN, high, low, close, volume,
        LEAD(daily_price, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS x1,
        LEAD(daily_price, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS x2,
        LEAD(daily_price, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE) AS x3
    FROM daily_price x0
)
SELECT
    x0.code as 'Stock',
    x1.date as 'From',
    x3.date as 'To',
    100*(x1.close - x0.close)/x0.close AS 'D+1 %',
    100*(x2.close - x1.close)/x1.close AS 'D+2 %',
    100*(x3.close - x2.close)/x2.close AS 'D+2 %'
FROM
    comparing_price
WHERE
    100*(x1.close - x0.close)/x0.close >= '30';
```

My Table's primary keys are stock name [code] and date [date] from [daily_price] DB.

It gives me syntax error from

```
...
FROM 
    comparing_price
WHERE
    100*(x1.close - x0.close)/x0.close >= '30';
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  `lead()` is much simpler:

```
SELECT dp.*,
       LEAD(price) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date) as next_price,
       LEAD(price, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date) as next_price_2,
       LEAD(price, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date) as next_price_3
  FROM daily_price dp;
```

One caveat:  This assumes that all codes have rows for each days.  In a table called `daily_price` that seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Thank you!! How about my second question? I got stock price table that does not include daily %change. I'm trying to make query using:

'100*(x1.close - x0.close)/x0.close'

Comment: Tag your question with the database product you are using.  Extracting weekdays from dates is DB-dependent.

Comment: Notice that Gordon's solution uses proximity of rows in sort order.  If you filter dates before using it in the above query to remove weekend dates, then Friday dates will be followed by Monday, right?

Comment: @koguma . . . Actually, this works for whatever days you have in the database.  The caveat is that it is not *checking* the day values, so if a day is missing for another reason, it just goes to the next day.

Comment: Attached my DB to the question. Also, I calculate successive dates under "FROM" command, whereas you go from "SELECT" command. I have attached my specific query to see if you can help me out how to apply this Lead() method to my query! Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @koguma . . . You need to use a subquery or CTE if you want to use the values in a `WHERE` clause.